# How to use JWT for asp.net core APIs and cookies for MVC separately

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have APIs and MVC in a project, in seperate folders. I want to use JWT for api/v1/so on and cookies for MVC , so far I have used JWT and authurize attributes on each api controller to be protected. I want to use Tokens based authorization for APIs route and cookies for MVC. The main problem is I cant find way to validated JWTs manually or it can be automated, like say I have api/v1/customers/{name}/addresses , the JWT that are being issued have username in each so I want to validated if token username matches the url {username} otherwise say "you cant use this token with that username". Following is what I have done so far. Your guidance is highly appreciated. Thank You

//JWT in Startup.cs

```
  app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions
        {
            AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
            AutomaticChallenge = true,
            TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
            {
                ValidIssuer = Configuration["Tokens:Issuer"],
                ValidAudience = Configuration["Tokens:Audidence"],
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Tokens:Key"])),
                ValidateLifetime = true
            }

        });
```

//route setting

```
 app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                template: "api/v1/{controller}/{id?}");

        });
```

//Api controller

```
[Route("api/v2/[controller]")]
[Authorize]
// here I want request only be Authorized if url username matches in token username
public class CustomerController : Controller
{

    [HttpGet("{userName}/addresses")]
    public IActionResult GetCredentials(string userName)
    {

      some logic...

    }

}
```

//Thanks, I changed the code, just showing to make sure I am doing the right way.

```
app.UseWhen(context => !context.Request.Path.Value.StartsWith("/api"), builder =>
        {
            app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions
            {
                AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
                AutomaticChallenge = true,
                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidIssuer = Configuration["Tokens:Issuer"],
                    ValidAudience = Configuration["Tokens:Audidence"],
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Tokens:Key"])),
                    ValidateLifetime = true
                }

            });
        });
```

Comment: seems like you could use app.Map or app.MapWhen to only use the jwtmiddleware for /api then use cookies for everything else https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware

Comment: Read up on `UseWhen` instead of `MapWhen`

Comment: Thanks its working fine, but can you guide how can I validate JWT based on username in the url and in JWT.

Comment: @Rohit I do not under stand your update. you said that you wanted to use the jwt for api call yet you have a negation in the predicate.

Comment: Yes you are right but if I dont put negation the api doesnt load, nothing loads, keeping looping like

Comment: its working now I had forgotten using builder lamda. Thanks Nkosi